# Slider & Light Box - Javascript conflict

Tags: javascript, slider, gallery, lightbox

Would you anyone please help resolve this conflict? I would really appreciate that.

I am trying to use two javascripts of Slider and Light Box from w3schools.com on one HTML page but, I guess, both javascripts use the same names(or values) for each function so when I use them in one page at the same time, they don't work. but when I remove one set of css/html/javascript for each slider or light box, either works well.

Please help this for me.
Thank you very much in advance.

CSS

```
<style>
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

/* --------- Slider ---------- */

* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.mySlides {
    display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
/* -----  Light Box -------*/
.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
 clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  border: none;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
 color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
 color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)
}
.container {margin: 0 auto; max-width: 1000px;}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <!--  ================  Slideshow  ================ -->
    <div class="slideshow-container mt20 mb10">
        <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:10px;">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div> <!-- // Slider -->

    <!-- Lightbox -->

    <h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox</h2>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="myLightBox" class="modal">
      <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="LB-Slides">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="LB-Slides">
          <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="LB-Slides">
          <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="LB-Slides">
          <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

        <div class="caption-container">
          <p id="caption"></p>
        </div>


        <div class="column">
          <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Trolltunga, Norway">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- // Lightbox -->
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>

/* ---------  Slider  ----------  */
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);
setInterval(function(){ showSlides(++slideIndex); }, 4000);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}   



/* ---------  LightBox  ---------- */
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myLightBox').style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myLightBox').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("LB-Slides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
/* ---------  //LightBox  ---------- */

</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all – yes, you are right, both of your scripts are conflicting to each other due the same methods names. Since it's written in global scope (window) you basically override each other functionality.

You could try to use JavaScript module pattern to isolate scope of each of your "widgets", even if you gonna use the same methods names, your code will be executed in it's own scope.

As quick example how to rewrite this into modules:

http://jsbin.com/pipajawiwa/1/edit?html,js,output

```
/* ---------  Slider  ----------  */

var slider = (function() {
    var slider = {};

    slider.setIntervals = function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            slider.showSlides(++slider.slideIndex);
        }, 4000);
    };
    slider.plusSlides = function(n) {
        slider.showSlides(slider.slideIndex += n);
    };
    slider.currentSlide = function(n) {
        slider.showSlides(slider.slideIndex = n);
    };

    slider.showSlides = function(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        if (n > slides.length) {
            slider.slideIndex = 1
        }
        if (n < 1) {
            slider.slideIndex = slides.length
        }
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slider.slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slider.slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    };

    slider.init = function() {
        slider.slideIndex = 1;
        slider.showSlides(slider.slideIndex);
        slider.setIntervals();
    };

    return slider;
})();


/* ---------  LightBox  ---------- */

var lightbox = (function() {
    var lightbox = {};

    lightbox.openModal = function() {
        document.getElementById('myLightBox').style.display = "block";
    };

    lightbox.closeModal = function() {
        document.getElementById('myLightBox').style.display = "none";
    };


    lightbox.plusSlides = function(n) {
        lightbox.showSlides(lightbox.slideIndex += n);
    };

    lightbox.currentSlide = function(n) {
        lightbox.showSlides(lightbox.slideIndex = n);
    };

    lightbox.showSlides = function(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("LB-Slides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
        if (n > slides.length) {
            lightbox.slideIndex = 1
        }
        if (n < 1) {
            lightbox.slideIndex = slides.length
        }
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[lightbox.slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        dots[lightbox.slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
        captionText.innerHTML = dots[lightbox.slideIndex - 1].alt;
    };

    lightbox.init = function() {
        lightbox.slideIndex = 1;
        lightbox.showSlides(lightbox.slideIndex);
    };

    return lightbox;
})();


slider.init(); // initialize slider module (widget);
lightbox.init(); // initialize lightbox module (widget);
```

Please make note that you also need to adjust your html onclick events, since it's should be called each widget methods, not global once.

P.S.: I'm not big fan of both of this code snippets from w3school (in terms of code quality, performance aspects, learning patterns), but it's completely another topic to discuss. But in order "to make it work" this link to jsbin above should help.